# could or allowed to

Tags: can-could

Are both examples acceptable?

1. As I had to go to the dentist, I was *allowed* to leave work early
2. As I had to go to the dentist, I *could* leave work early.

Does the implied permission legitimise the grammar?

Comment: Both are good. But the first one sounds better, maybe because it has overtones of politeness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commenter below shot down a lot of my grammatical points ;-) But the answer is the same. Both sentences are acceptable. The first sentence implies you have and need permission. The second doesn't emphasize this as much.

Comment: Neither first clause is in the past perfect.  Only the first second clause is the simple past.  The second second clause uses the past form of the modal auxiliary *can*.  The simple past would be *I left work early*. "I could" is not a verb as it contains a subject.  *Could* is past tense but it's not an active (i.e. transitive) verb.  The first sentence doesn't imply permssion; it states it.  The second likely carries the aspect of permission, but *could* sometimes has the aspect of ability.  Other than that....

Comment: You make some good points. I actually didn't know about modal verbs. Thanks for teaching me about them. Although I have to say, some of your points are pedantic.

Comment: What do you mean by *pedantic*?  Correct? I wish you could have emphasized the variety of aspects that *could* could carry.  For instance, what would this mean:  *As I no longer needed the crutches, I **could** leave work early*?